# Display nested list with doctrine2 and zf2

Tags: recursion, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Following this [tutorial](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/simple-nested-sets-in-doctrine-2) and putting in all together to make it work in my project, just to display a nested list (using doctrine 2 and zf2) , I can not enter into the foreach. Using this snippet of code:

```
    $root_categories        = $em->getRepository('Controleitor\Model\Entity\Category')->findBy(array('parent_category' => null));
    $collection             = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($root_categories);
    $category_iterator  = new \MYMODULE\Model\Entity\RecursiveCategoryIterator($collection);
    $recursive_iterator     = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator( $category_iterator, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($recursive_iterator as $index => $child_category){
        echo 'test';         
    }
    Debug::dump($recursive_iterator);die;
```

I'm expecting to print the 'test' string but it only print this:

```
    object(RecursiveIteratorIterator)#414 (0) {}
```

But when I do before the dump:

```
    $recursive_iterator->current()->getTitle();
```

I got the title.. It fails somehow looping the \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection object.

Comment: i presume that $category_iterator is either returing only 1 object which may mean there is no child within a child or other words parent may not have children.

Comment: Also can you  post both of Entites i.e Iterator  and categories?

Comment: Please use XDebug and `var_dump`. The doctrine/common debug utility is opinionated.

Comment: Please check `RecursiveCategoryIterator#valid()`. If you have just copy-pasted the tutorial code, the iterator will only work with objects of type `\Entity\Category`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using different Debug class instead of Doctrine's one, that may the suspect. Try Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump().

Explain comes from [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html):

> Lazy load proxies always contain an instance of Doctrine’s
>   EntityManager and all its dependencies. Therefore a var_dump() will
>   possibly dump a very large recursive structure which is impossible to
>   render and read. You have to use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump() to
>   restrict the dumping to a human readable level. Additionally you
>   should be aware that dumping the EntityManager to a Browser may take
>   several minutes, and the Debug::dump() method just ignores any
>   occurrences of it in Proxy instances.

Comment: it's helpful to know it, but it doesn't help with this issue because I can't get into the loop as I expect. The output of the Doctrine Debug is: "object(stdClass)#415 (1) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(25) "RecursiveIteratorIterator" } "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've discussed with the author of this tutorial, he recommended me to check the valid() function of the RecursiveCategoryIterator class and there was the problem.
Since I was using "use" statetment and left a backslash before th class name:

```
use Entity\Category;    
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class RecursiveCategoryIterator implements \RecursiveIterator
{
//.......
public function valid()
{
    return $this->posts->current() instanceof \Category;
}
```

There ware two ways to solve this problem:
1. To remove the backslash:

```
    return $this->posts->current() instanceof Category;
```

2. To use full namespace:

```
use Entity\Category; // remove this line
//.......
    return $this->posts->current() instanceof \Entity\Category;
```

Hope that helps.